# Function that do addition or subtraction randomly

Tags: r, random, addition, subtraction

I wonder if there is a function that can do addition or subtraction operator randomly:

```
x +- y
```

Comment: `x + sample(c(-1,1),size=1)*y`

Comment: @MaratTalipov If that works, post it as an answer.  Explain how it works in your answer.

Comment: I interpreted the request to be satisfied by: `x + sample(c(-1,1),size=length(x),repl=TRUE)*y`

Comment: Another chance for reverse-code-golf!  :-) .    `doit <- runif(1); doit<-if(doit>0.5) 1 else 0; switch(doit, x+y, x-y)`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The question boils down to getting `-1` or `1` in random fashion. You can get it using `sample`:

```
x + sample(c(-1,1),size=1)*y
```

or `runif`:

```
x + sign(runif(n=1,min=-1,max=1))*y
```

If `x` and `y` are vectors, you can generate sequence of numbers `-1` and `1` of the same length as the length of `x`, as @BondedDust suggested:

```
x + sample(c(-1,1),size=length(x),replace=T)*y
```

Comment: ...and you can always wrap it up in your own infix operator if you really want: `'%rand%' <- function(x,y){x + sample(c(1,-1),length(y),replace = TRUE) * y}`